# Select Option from dropdown list

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectors

I have a dynamic dropdown list which has value attribute set up as "4107,2632". When I apply filter I have only one value as 4107 which is available in the dropdown option in value attribute. The rendered html for dropdown list is

```
<select id="ddlFilterGoal">
    <option value="All">Goals / Folders</option>
    <option value="4124,2632">1234567890 (APPp PUB)</option>
    <option value="4123,2645">aaaa sdsssss (NNN Employee)</option>
    <option value="4088,2629">Default (nb nb)</option>
    <option value="4107,2632">Goal with start date only (APPp PUB)</option>
</select>
```

Now I am trying to select the option like this

```
$("#ddlFilterGoal option:value:contains('4107')").val(); - no error but option not get selected, it gives the default option "All" 
$("#ddlFilterGoal option:[value:contains('4107')"]).val(); - error with "]"
```

Please suggest me what I am doing wrong and how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safest way to do this.

You might have another option with value that contains string 4107 ex:- 41072 etc. So best way is to filter out the exact value that you are looking for.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VeqRe/)

```
alert($("#ddlFilterGoal option").filter(function(){
     return $.inArray('4107' ,this.value.split(',')) > -1;
}).first().val());
```

or

```
alert($("#ddlFilterGoal option").filter(function(){
     return $.inArray('4107' ,this.value.split(',')) > -1;
}).get(0).value);
```

Contains selector will match the following one too as it contains `4107` in the value but actual you are looking for is 4107.

```
  <option value="41077,2632">Goal with start date only (APPp PUB)</option>
```

More Precisely:-

```
var match=$("#ddlFilterGoal option").filter(function(){
     return $.inArray('4107' ,this.value.split(',')) > -1;
}).get(0); //<-- Remove get(0) to get array of values incase of multiple matches.

if(match)
    alert(match.value); 
else
    alert('No match');
```

Comment: yeah, i had considered the fact that the value could be present in multiple option elements.. but that wasn't specified and I figured the issue was really with the selector.

Comment: well, regardless of the values being 4107 or it being present as a substring.. but anyways, it's a fair point

Comment: I am using "jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js" but I am getting error Object #<Object> has no method 'first'

Comment: Its not with jqueryui it is in jquery. You dont need to use first(). remove it and check.

Comment: Yup Contains is little tricky.. mostly we use it for text match to apply styles or something like that, but for data processing like this this could cause unexpected issues..

Answer (score 4):

`$("#ddlFilterGoal option[value*='4107']").val();`

For more info, see: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

*Note: this answer provides insight into the solution for what you were trying to do re: contains. I haven't assumed what your data looks like, so this answer doesn't suggest to use this for looking up option values in a select list, rather, it provides insight into how to use the attribute contains selector*